# How to get length of "static const unsigned char my_var[]"

Tags: c++, string, string-length

My var is:

```
static const unsigned char joey[] = 
{
    0xFF, 
    0xD8, 
    0xFF, 
    0xE1
};
```

How can I get lenght of it?

Comment: Simply `sizeof(joey)`, as long `joey` is in scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For array size, you may do

```
std::size_t len = sizeof(joey) / sizeof(joey[0]);
```

Or with a safer way

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t get_size(const T(&)[N]) { return N; }

std::size_t len = get_size(joey);
```